# Bundle install freezing on sassc during Rails server deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app using capistrano. The deployment script, initiated by `cap production deploy` runs fine, until this command:

`$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/app/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --debug --backtrace --quiet`

I ssh'd into the server and run the same command, but replaced the `--quiet` flag with `--verbose`, and see the bundle is frozen on sassc installation:

```
Using activestorage 6.0.3.2
Using actionmailbox 6.0.3.2
Using webpacker 4.2.2
Using actiontext 6.0.3.2
Using rails 6.0.3.2
Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
```

From my extensive research, I understand that installing with native extensions may take very long, but no matter how long I let it run, nothing happens. I've manually installed the gem in verbose mode after leaving it running all night, and it appeared to have succeeded:

```
compiling ./libsass/src/position.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/prelexer.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/remove_placeholders.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/sass.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/sass2scss.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/sass_context.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/sass_functions.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/sass_values.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/source.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/source_map.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/stylesheet.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/to_value.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/units.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/utf8_string.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/util.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/util_string.cpp
compiling ./libsass/src/values.cpp
linking shared-object sassc/libsass.so
current directory: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
"make \"DESTDIR=\" install"
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 libsass.so ./.gem.20200720-1092-b4v9ch/sassc
current directory: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200720-1092-1xt3w4b.rb extconf.rb
current directory: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
make "DESTDIR="
current directory: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
make "DESTDIR=" install
Successfully installed sassc-2.4.0
Parsing documentation for sassc-2.4.0
Parsing sources...
100% [261/261]  lib/sassc/version.rb
Done installing documentation for sassc after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but the deployment still freezes on `sassc`.

I am deploying on an AWS EC2 instance and noticed all my CPU Credits were depleted after a few hours of letting the deploy script run, so I even turned on unlimited mode to remedy this by paying for the extra CPU cycles. However, I've let the script run for days to no avail. I'm truly at a loss, and this is very frustrating.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well you've got a proper mystery on your hands. That gem shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes to build...on a Raspberry Pi. No need to let it go for days, or even hours. I've been looking at `bundle install` but I'm not sure how to get it to be any more verbose about what it's doing.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've been stumped on this for over a week now, so if you have any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/189 seems to the culprit. Downgrading to an earlier version might fix this (2.1.0 is suggested).

See also https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/204.